# Close other site div from iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I have iframes on my website which point to content on a different domain.  This content is meant to be re-purposed and is ad supported.  There is 3-5 ad's on each page, each with their own close button.  I believe they are all in one div, id="bannerfloat22".  Is there a way to make a close button but target the div inside the frame? The codes I've tried only seem to work if the div is on MY page.

Example: I use this iframe on my page.

```
 <iframe src="http://coolsport.tv/kiwi25.html" name="25" width="650" height="480"></iframe>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe url is a different domain, then no - there is nothing you can do. If the iframe url is from your site's domain, then yes - you can target the DOM inside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks fellas.  I didn't think so but though I would ask the guru's!

Answer (score 0):

In short... No. Javascript from one domain cannot have any control over a DOM from another. This is a security issue - eg to stop a hidden iframe stealing login details for another site

For more information, read up on the [same origin policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)